# Unload non-visible HTML nodes

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am building a vue/vueitfy app displaying a very large amount of images (10-20k) in a grid view with some additional information. The images are grouped in several sections. Clicking on an image opens an overlay with the image in near full screen. The images are opened from local disk.

[image]

I use the  component to lazy load the sections of images when they come into the viewport (I think that uses the Intersection Observer API in the background). Following code is just to showcase the idea:

```
<script lang="ts">
export default {
  data: () => ({
    // list of urls to local blobs per section
    // total of 10 - 20k images in 1k sections
    imageURLsBySection: new Map() as Map<string, string[]>
  }),
  methods: {
    showOverlay() {
      // ...
    }
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <v-lazy v-for="(section, imageURLs) in imageURLsBySection" :key="section" min-height="500">
    <span>{{ section }}</span>
    <v-row>
      <v-col v-for="(imageURL, index) in imageURLs" :key="index" cols="2">
        <v-img :src="imageURL" @click="showOverlay()"/>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-lazy>
</template>
```

Scrolling is always smooth and fast. Opening / closing the overlay is also fast **in the beginning**.

**The problem:** After some time of scrolling the DOM is of course getting really large as step by step the empty v-lazy divs get filled with content. This leads to opening / closing the overlay getting slower and slower. I assume the reason for the slowness is that re-rendering the page takes so long due to the huge DOM.

My idea would be to not only lazy load image sections when they come into screen, but also unload them when the user scrolled passed them. So that i replace a section of images with an empty div of the same size.

But I'm struggling to find a way how to implement that. Ideally while still using the  component.
Checking `!entry.isIntersecting` I don't know whether it was already seen. And would I create one observer for all sections or one per section?

Could anyone please show me a base concept of how I would implement that?

**EDIT**:
Trying the suggested solution from @MarcHanna with `content-visibility: auto` didn't help. When only using that without any lazy loading the page is extremely slow to open the overlay.

This brings me to the assumption that rendering is not the problem, but rather Vue taking so long to update the DOM after the user requests the overlay. The virtual DOM is huge without any lazy loading and comparing that to the equally huge real DOM every time the reactive data changes (overlay show / hide flag)  probably causes the big lag. Does that make sense?

Comment: There are still issues with browser compatability, but this is exactly the sort of use case that [`content-visibility: auto;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content-visibility) is intended to help with. It's been in Chromium for quite a while, but it's still in development in Firefox and Safari hasn't shipped it yet either. There's some more info here too: [Content visibility in Chromium](https://web.dev/content-visibility/)

Comment: @MarkHanna - so, that's a useless CSS property 

Comment: @LemonGraZ you might find it useful to watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FFA-v-CIxJQ) from HTTP203, which goes over an example. As well as setting `content-visibility: auto;` you will also need to use [`contain-intrinsic-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/contain-intrinsic-size) to tell the browser how large to pretend your container is when its contents aren't being rendered. Otherwise they'll collapse to nothing and all enter the viewport at once

Comment: @MarkHanna Thank you! I tried it, also completely without <v-lazy> lazy loading. The performance does not improve. 
So I assume, that rendering is not the problem, but the fact that vue has to create such a bug virtual dom and compare that huge thing everytime some data changes (e.g. show / hide overlay). Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for all who are wondering: The answer are **virtual lists**.

In vuetify this can be done using the `<v-virtual-scroll>` component.

This basically only adds the visible items (plus some buffer) to the DOM and keeps it small this way.